Location of gnuplot table with pgfplots
I'm making tikz plot with gnuplot, using the standalone package. The main tex file and the one with the tikz code reside in different directories. pgfplots complains that it cannot find the gnuplot-result file. I've tried setting the prefix and id parameters, without success.
Here are the two files for a MWE, the tikz file is in the tikz_dir directory, child of the directory where the main tex file resides.
Main tex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone[mode=tex]{/tmp/test_dir/tikz}
\end{document}

/tmp/test_dir/tikz.tex file
\documentclass{article}  
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[prefix={/tmp/test_dir/},id=tikz]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot gnuplot {cos(2*pix)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Finally found the reason for this problem. Gnuplot wasn't properly installed… The code posted in the question works.

@wilk,
I was able to get this to work under linux using lualatex with some relatively minor changes:

In main.tex, replace the leading "/" in the folder name with "./". In this context the directory specified should be relative to the main.tex file directory:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone[mode=tex]{./tmp/test_dir/tikz}
\end{document}


In tikz.tex, a) remove the prefix altogether, and b) change 2*pix to 2*pi*x:

\documentclass{article}  
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[id=tikz]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot gnuplot {cos(2*pi*x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This may not work depending on your operating system, LaTeX engine, etc.
Hope this helps.


I just noticed you're using \RequirePackage in your tikz.tex file. This macro is only typically used in .sty files. LaTeX code should use \usepackage. Also, as @pascal974 pointed out, the \RequirePackage{tikz} is redundant - pgfplots loads it already.

Finally found the reason for this problem. Gnuplot wasn't properly installed… The code posted in the question works.


replace 2pix with 2pi*x
Without prefix

The first compilation creates a .gnuplot file
you have to open it with the gnuplot application. a .table file is then created.
The second compilation, we get the .pdf
In the pgfmanual's documentation section 22.6 Plotting a Function Using Gnuplot
\documentclass{article}  
% \RequirePackage{tikz}%<<-- chaged by pgfplots
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<<-- added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [id=tikz]
    \begin{axis}
    % \addplot gnuplot {cos(2*pix)};
    \addplot gnuplot {cos(2*pi*x)};%<< pi*x
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I can't use prefix, I have an error message when I open the .gnuplot file

The missing is a stupid typo but fixing doesn't change the problem. I can of course generate the pdf file from the tikz file and include it but because I have some complicated setup with the package animate, and several such images in the document, it would be more convenient for me to use the standalone feature.
